# Multi-label out-of-core learning for text data: ValueError on partial fit

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I am trying to build a multi-label out-of-core text classifier. As described [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_out_of_core_classification.html), the idea is to read (large scale) text data sets in batches and partially fitting them to the classifiers. Additionally, when you have multi-label instances as described [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html), the idea is to build that many binary classifiers as the number of classes in the data set, in an One-Vs-All manner.

When combining the MultiLabelBinarizer and OneVsRestClassifier classes of sklearn with partial fitting I get the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

The code is the following:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier

categories = ['a', 'b', 'c']
X = ["This is a test", "This is another attempt", "And this is a test too!"]
Y = [['a', 'b'],['b'],['a','b']]

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=categories)
vectorizer = HashingVectorizer(decode_error='ignore', n_features=2 ** 18,         non_negative=True)
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(MultinomialNB(alpha=0.01))

X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X)
Y_train = mlb.fit_transform(Y)
clf.partial_fit(X_train, Y_train, classes=categories)
```

You can imagine that the last three lines are applied to each minibatch, the code of which I have removed for the sake of simplicity.

If you remove the OneVsRestClassifier and use MultinomialNB only, the code runs fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing y_train as transformed from `MultiLabelBinarizer` which are in the form of [[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]], but passing categories as `['a','b','c']` which is then passed through [this line the code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/multiclass.py#L260):-

```
if np.setdiff1d(y, self.classes_):
raise ValueError(("Mini-batch contains {0} while classes " +
                 "must be subset of {1}").format(np.unique(y),
                                              self.classes_))
```

which results in a array of boolean values such as [False, True, ..].
`if` cannot handle such arrays as a single truth value and hence the error.

First thing is you should pass classes in same numerical format as `Y_train`.
Now even if you do that, then the [internal `label_binarizer_` of OneVsRestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html#sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier) will decide that it is of type "multiclass" rather than `multilabel` and will then refuse to transform the classes correctly. This in my opinion is a bug in OneVsRestClassifer and/or LabelBinarizer.

Please submit an issue to scikit-learn github about `partial_fit` and see what happens.

**Update**
Apparently, deciding "multilabel" or "multiclass" from target vector (y) is a currenlty ongoing issue on scikit-learn because of all the complications surrounding it.

- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7665
- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5959
- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7931
- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8098
- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7628
- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/2626

Comment: Apparently the problem lies in the OneVsRestClassifie because the partial fit of Naive Bayes works fine even with that type of categories. I guess for now I should make my own one vs rest approach.

Answer (score 4):

So maybe a different answer then you'd expect, but I would recommend that you don't use the OneVsRestClassifier in favour of using the [scikit-multilearn](http://scikit.ml/) library built on top of scikit-learn, that provides multi-label classifier which are more state of the art than the simple OneVsRest.

You can find an example of how to use scikit-multilearn in the [tutorial](http://scikit.ml/api/classify.html#classifying-input-using-scikit-multilearn). A review of approaches to multi-label classification can be found in [Tsoumakas's introduction to MLC](http://lpis.csd.auth.gr/publications/tsoumakas-ijdwm.pdf).

But if it happens that you have label's that are co-occurring with each other, I would recommend using a different classifier for example Label Powerset with label space division using fast greedy community detection on the output space - I explain why this works in [my paper about label space division](http://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/18/8/282/htm).

Converting your code to use scikit-multilearn would make it look as follows:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

from skmultilearn.ensemble import LabelSpacePartitioningClassifier
from skmultilearn.cluster import IGraphLabelCooccurenceClusterer
from skmultilearn.problem_transform import LabelPowerset

categories = ['a', 'b', 'c']
X = ["This is a test", "This is another attempt", "And this is a test too!"]
Y = [['a', 'b'],['b'],['a','b']]

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=categories)
vectorizer = HashingVectorizer(decode_error='ignore', n_features=2 ** 18,         non_negative=True)

X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X)
Y_train = mlb.fit_transform(Y)

# base single-label classifier 
base_classifier = MultinomialNB(alpha=0.01)

# problem transformation from multi-label to single-label 
transformation_classifier = LabelPowerset(base_classifier)

# clusterer dividing the label space using fast greedy modularity maximizing scheme
clusterer = IGraphLabelCooccurenceClusterer('fastgreedy', weighted=True, include_self_edges=True) 

# ensemble
clf = LabelSpacePartitioningClassifier(transformation_classifier, clusterer)

clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Comment: I appreciate your approach, but it seems like skmulitlearn does not support partial_fit. I'd say skmultilearn is thus not applicable to multi-label **out-of-core** learning.